# NodeJS basic POST request - Socket hung up

Tags: forms, node.js, post, http-post

I am currently playing around with NodeJS and I have created a GET request fine, no issues with that, as soon as I try and post something to a form, I get 'socket hung up' error.

Here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var mathResult = 123;

var options = {
    host: 'directus.darkscience.net',
    path: '/',
    port: '6789',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded'
    }
};

var post_req = http.request(options, function(res){
    console.log('HERE');

    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log('CHUNK');
        var result = chunk.match(/correct/i);
        if(result.length > 0){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});

post_req.on('error', function(e){
    console.log('Post Error : ' + e.message);
});

post_req.end('amount='+mathResult);
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have added a listener to the request for "end". Like: request.addListener( "end", function()

Does that work for you, instead of putting end outside the http.request?

Comment: It means that the server closed the socket. Maybe because he haves some security like: you need to provide an header "content-length"